# rest framework browsable API's interface is not working

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm using rest framework for my backend and when I enter my site browsable API doesn't display properly! you can see that in the image.[image: browsable interface is not working]

Answer (score 0):

I should have installed whitenoise library.